# *Pointer = - *Pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I've only been doing C for a few weeks so I am quite new to it.

I've seen things like

```
* (variable-name) = -* (variable-name)
```

in lecture notes but what exactly would it do? Would it just negate the value being pointed to?

Comment: Yes, it would. (So, that's not quite `pointer = -pointer`, but rather `pointed_object = -pointed_object`.)

Comment: Thought it would have been something simple, and noted. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Note `*ptr *= -1;` is shorter.

Comment: @wildplasser Usually but not if the name of the variable is single letter: `*i = -*i;` (7 signs).... `*i *= -1;` (7 signs). I think you should adjust your comment.

Comment: Duh! I meant: easier to read. The human brain needs to lookup only one identifier, and does not need to check if LHS and RHS are equal. IMHO the -1 constant is so common that it will be recognised without lookup ...

Comment: Note that for simple pointer variables (e.g. `int *ptr`), the parentheses are unnecessary (`*ptr = -*ptr` is unambiguous).  For more complex pointer expressions, the parentheses could be necessary: `*(ptr+3) = -*(ptr+3);`, for example, but then why not write `ptr[3] = -ptr[3];` anyway?  However, the parentheses are not 'wrong'; they're merely unnecessary in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you add the star it means it is pointing to the value.
It is essentially saying: to the value at address (variable-name), become -1* the value of (variable-name).

If you are new to C, you may find it easier to use & instead of pointers. &'s are essentially the opposite of *. & doesn't point, it gives the address of a variable (which I find to be a simpler concept).

The following is an example which should demonstrate the use of `*` and `&`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int blah = 6;
    int *num = &blah;
    (*num) = -(*num);
    printf("%d\n", num); //Displays num
}
```

Comment: This is not C, my friend.

Comment: I use C++, which is pretty similiar, but it demonstrates the point.

Comment: Nope, they are two different languages.

Comment: @ZacWimer the languages are different and OP may not be familiar with C++-ism.

Comment: They are, but C++ was born from C. And both functions exist the same in both C and C++. The structure is the same, so it demonstrates the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Fair enough ouah. Does my edit make it better? The use of the two should be the same since C++ came from C

Comment: @ZacWimer not really, you should get rid of C++ in question tagged C. Use `stdio.h` and `printf` here.

Comment: And while you are at it, use `int main(void)` instead of `main()` which has been obsoleted in C.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ouah, I'm kind of new to stackoverflow so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it negates the value being pointed to. We cannot write operations on addresses so operations are done on deferenced pointers. Here, `*d = -*c` means:

```
*d = (-1) * (*c)
```

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int *c;
    int *d;
    d = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    c = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *c = 9;
    *d = -*c;
    printf("%d", *d);
    free(c);
    free(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some whitespace. (Note: before K&R2 `*d=-*c;` had a different meaning)

Comment: @wildplasser: if you're thinking of the old-style assignment operators `=-` instead of `-=`, then even K&R 1 used the new versions.  See [What does `=+` mean in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573978/what-does-mean-in-c/7578156#7578156)

Comment: You say _We cannot write operations on addresses_, but that's not entirely accurate.  You can add or subtract an integer from an address, or take the difference of two addresses (to two objects in the same array), but you can't multiply or divide addresses, nor can you negate them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [yes] IIRC it was (at least) still accepted by compilers, often with a warning. Not too sure about K&R1, though.

Comment: @wildplasser: I believe your compiler would have had to be older than 1980 for it to accept `=-` as the modern `-=`. The old notation was phased out before AT&T 7th Edition UNIX was released in 1979, and before K&R 1st Edition was published. I've not double-checked Lyons analysis of 6th Edition UNIX; I'd not be very surprised to find the old notation was used in that.

Comment: My memory may be fogged. Could even be that the acceptance of `=-` needed an explicit flag. Trying to dig up K&R1 from the web.