# Bad address in my write-function

Tags: c++, mmap

I have to code this little task and can´t find my mistake. It should just read some data from a file and copy it in opposite order into another one. The first part seems to work, but the while-part gives me "Bad Address" for every time the write function is used. I´m grateful for every idea!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


#define TRY(cmd,msg) {                                          \
    if ((cmd) < 0) {                                            \
      std::cerr << (msg) << ": " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;       \
    }                                                                   \
  }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int fd_in, fd_out, rest;
    off_t map_size, offset, length;
    char * addr;    
    struct stat sb;

    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: kopfstand in out" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if ((fd_in = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((fd_out = open(argv[2],O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR)) == -1){
        close(fd_in);
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }


    fstat(fd_in, &sb);
    length = sb.st_size;
    map_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    rest = length % map_size;
    offset = length -rest;

    if(rest != 0){
        addr = (char*)mmap(NULL, rest, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd_in, offset);
        if(addr == MAP_FAILED){
            perror("Error mmaping the File");
        }

        for (int off = rest-1;  off >= 0; --off){
            TRY(write(fd_out, addr+off, 1),"write");
        }

        if(munmap((char*)addr, rest)== -1){
            perror("munmap");
        }
    }


    while(offset > 0){
        offset =- map_size;

        addr = (char*)mmap(NULL, map_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd_in, offset);
        if(addr == MAP_FAILED){
            perror("Error mmaping the File");
        }
        for(int off = map_size-1; off >= 0; --off){
           TRY(write(fd_out, addr+off, 1),"write");
        }   


        if(munmap((char*)addr, map_size) == -1){
           perror("munmap");
        }   
    }

    close(fd_in);
    close(fd_out);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to do to solve this problem?  also it would help us and yourself if you broke this into functions.

Comment: Print out all those variables before the `if` statement, that may provide a clue.

Comment: ok, these are the important functions, i deleted the rest. @paxdiablo i tryed to print them and everything looks like i should. Do you have an idea, what could cause this "bad address" problem?

Comment: Replace the `TRY` macro with an inline function.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews do you have an example? Sorry i´m not very experienced with c/c++

Comment: Use a debugger to see exactly where it's crashing.

Comment: Yeah, it did this before, the problem is in the write function, but i cant find the reason why

Comment: Compile with warnings. You have simple typo.

Comment: I compile with -Wall

Comment: Maybe get a better compiler, or inspect the code carefully yourself. `clang` identifies the issue.

Comment: GCC 4.9.1 with lots of warnings enabled does not report the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself!  (I kicked myself when I finally spotted the problem!)

This line:

```
    offset =- map_size;
```

should be:

```
    offset -= map_size;
```

See also [What does `=+` mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573978/what-does-mean-in-c/7578156#7578156)

One of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262296/bad-address-in-my-write-function/27263547#comment42998834_27262296) to the question by [Andrew Medico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19405/andrew-medico) observes that `clang` identifies the problem immediately — and it does:

```
$ clang -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror badadd.cpp -o badadd
    badadd.cpp:65:16: error: use of unary operator that may be intended as compound assignment (-=)
          [-Werror]
            offset =- map_size;
```

G++ (GCC) 4.9.1 (home-built on Mac OS X 10.9 and running on 10.10.1) with the same compiler options does not identify the problem.

<sup>*JFTR: I found the problem the hard way (with print statements tracing the value of `offset`), and only read Andrew's comment after finding and posting the answer.*</sup>

Comment: `clang` (from Xcode 6.1) prints the warning even in its default invocation (with no extra warning switches).

Comment: @AndrewMedico: interesting — I'm surprised that it is a common enough problem to warrant the analysis.  The C compilers that supported `=-` (and `=+`, etc) were obsolete before about 1980. I think it is the first time I've seen the issue reported on SO (but I've not looked at every C and C++ question to make sure).

Comment: ohh man, i´m kicking myself so hard right now. i was awake until 5am because of this! Thanks for your help