# =+ operator in c++?

Tags: c++, operators

I have a question on a program that includes the following if statement:

```
if (x =+ 4){
    x += 5;
}
```

I've never seen anything like that before, surely it isn't a typo? Does =+ actually do anything?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Note that a decent compiler will issue a warning for this code, provided you are using a reasonably high warning level.

Comment: Although not actually a C / C++ operator, I have often wished that it was, so that I could write A*B=+C rather than C+=A*B.

Answer (score 20):

```
x =+ 4
```

means

```
x= (+4)
```

or simply

```
x=4
```

though such construction syntactically correct and can be compiled, does not make much sense and most probably a typo, where `x==4` was intended, especially that it is used as condition for `if`

Answer (score 2):

In the early days of C, `=+` was the same as `+=`, but that's long gone and never made its way into C++.

---

`=+a` is understood to be `= (+a)`

The unary `+` operator promotes the argument to an `int` if it's of a narrower type, otherwise it's a no-op.

And `=` is regular assignment.

---

You can contrive a difference between `=+` and `=` in this way:

If `=` was twice overloaded for two particular pairings, for example {`Foo`, `int`} and {`Foo`, `char`}, and you had an instance of `Foo` `foo` and a `char c`, then

```
foo = c // calls the overload taking a `char`
```

and

```
foo =+ c // calls the overload taking an `int`
```

*would* call different overloads.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my initial answer was due to foolishly misreading the question.

The correct answer, is this code simply assigns x the value of positive 4,
because this is then non zero it satisfies the if and increments it further by 5.

A simpler form of this program in its current state would be:

```
x = 9;
```

However I strongly suspect there was a typo involved and the statement inside the if condition should either be `x == 4`, `x += 4` or `x != 4` depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

OK just to round this out, I did find that my hunch was right, =+ and =- are indeed just obsolete forms of the += and -= op's in use today:

Stack Overflow: [What does =+ mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573978/what-does-mean-in-c/7574006)
https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/unix/digital/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_064.HTM (now that's a vintage web page!)

and specifically

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C

tells us that they were changed: "Compound assignment operators of the form =op (such as =-) were changed to the form op= (that is, -=) to remove the semantic ambiguity created by constructs such as i=-10, which had been interpreted as i =- 10 (decrement i by 10) instead of the possibly intended i = -10 (let i be -10)."

So it's not to do with making an argument explicitly +ve or -ve. You can simply substitute the modern forms, eg use += in place of =+.

Comment: You could delete your other, now obsolete answers in favor of this one. Also note that you are referencing C, but this question is about C++.

Comment: I''ve deleted your previous 'answers', this isn't a forum, you can *[edit]* your answers to improve them.